# Route doesn't render correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

dear users, I've faced a problem with React Router. I've 2 components:
`DriverPage.js` and `UserTrans.js`.

```
<Route path={`${adminBase}/users/:id`} component={DriverPage}/>
<Route path={`${adminBase}/users/id/userTrans`} component={UserTransactions}/>
```

I need to go to the `UserTransactions` component by clicking the `<Link>` in `DriverPage` component. But I also use Modal window in `DriverPage` accordingly to the documentation.

`<Link>` which opens Modal

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `${location.pathname}/editUser`,
  state: {
  background: location,
  type: 'editUser',
  data: {
  fullName, 
  phone, 
  mail, 
 }
 }
}}>
  <Btn id="editUser" classNames="menu-btn">edit Data</Btn>
</Link>
```

Condition with `<Route>` of modal

```
let background = location.state && location.state.background;
{background && <Route path={match.url} children={<Popup type={location.state.type} data={location.state.data}/>} />}
```

And `<Link>` which redirects to the `UserTransactions`:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `${params.id}/userTrans`,
  state: {
   userId: params.id
  }
}}>
 <Btn>Все транзакции пользователя</Btn>
</Link>
```

The problem is when I click on the `UserTransaction` Link the URL changes but nothing happens and I'm still staying on the `DriverPage`. When I add `exact` attribute to the `DriverPage` Route the `UserTransaction` components work but Modal doesn't.

Comment: You need to move your Route `${adminBase}/users/id/userTrans` above the `${adminBase}/users/:id` Route  and wrap them with `Switch` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `exact` to make sure it renders correctly

```
<Route exact path={`${adminBase}/users/id/userTrans`} component={UserTransactions}/>
<Route exact path={`${adminBase}/users/:id`} component={DriverPage}/>
```

Comment: Doing this way makes `UserTransaction` work but Modal isn't working.

Comment: Move `UserTransactions` route before `DriverPage`

Comment: omg, that helped, just exchanging the lines, 8 hours... thanks!